# sort list of nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, sorting, nested-lists

How to sort list of nested dictionaries? Actual list of dictionary is

```
[
   {
      "Name":"21_12",
      "Details":[
         {
            "name":"Cat",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":3,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":5,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Dog",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":1,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":2,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

where the inner list of dictionaries should be sorted with "id" even inside the "Data" and in the "Details"

the output required:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"21_12",
      "Details":[
         {
            "name":"Dog",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":1,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":2,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Cat",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":3,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":5,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Tried sorted inbuilt function. Didnt work as expected

Comment: Please format the JSON data in a code-block. You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```python
def order_structure(structure):
    for details in structure:
        sorted_detail = sorted(details["Details"], key=lambda x: max(x["Data"], key= lambda y: y["id"])["id"])
        details["Details"] = sorted_detail
        for data in details["Details"]:
            sorted_data = sorted(data["Data"], key= lambda x: x["id"])
            data["Data"] = sorted_data
    

order_structure(structure)
```

If you don't want to order it in-place, but want to generate an ordered copy, just do the same thing on `structure.copy()`

```python
def get_ordered_structure(structure):
    structure_copy = structure.copy()
    for details in structure_copy:
        sorted_detail = sorted(details["Details"], key=lambda x: max(x["Data"], key= lambda y: y["id"])["id"])
        details["Details"] = sorted_detail
        for data in details["Details"]:
            sorted_data = sorted(data["Data"], key= lambda x: x["id"])
            data["Data"] = sorted_data
    return structure_copy

ordered_structure = get_ordered_structure(structure)
```

In this way, the original structure doesn't change

The function works even if there is more than one element in the main list, if they follow the same structure.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The above code sorts the details list but also requires to be sorted inside Data list

Comment: Yes sorry the example I tried gave me the correct answer anyways, I edited the answer and now it should order bot "Details" and "Data".

Answer (score 0):

You can use python pandas to solve this problem.

```
myDictionary = [
   {
      "Name":"21_12",
      "Details":[
         {
            "name":"Cat",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":3,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":5,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Dog",
            "Data":[
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":1,
                  "loop_count":1
               },
               {
                  "status":"Passed",
                  "id":2,
                  "loop_count":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]

import pandas as pd
for i in range(len(myDictionary[0]["Details"])):
    df = pd.DataFrame(myDictionary[0]["Details"][i]["Data"])
    df.sort_values("id", inplace=True)
    myDictionary[0]["Details"][i]["Data"] = df.to_dict(orient="records")
    print(myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the python sorted function  with the right key function

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: x['Details']['Data']['id'])
```